# Typescript - Calling a class exported from another file.

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a file called searchBar.ts in which contains a init() function that I wish to call in a file called index.ts.

My searchBar.ts file looks like this:

```
class searchBar {
    init() {
        console.log('work you C*&*T')
    }
}

export let searchBarClass = new searchBar;
```

I then want to be able to call this function in index.ts. I am currently trying to do this with the below code but init is never found with my intellisense:

```
import { searchBarClass } from './modules/searchBar';

class Main {
    searchBarClass.init()
}

let main = new Main();
export {main}
```

Later on I then want to wrap the function in a global function that I'll call in the HTML file.

Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to export a class and call the init() method on the object instance:

```
export class SearchBar {
    init() {
        console.log('work you C*&*T')
    }
}
```

Then accessing it from another file:

```
import { SearchBar } from './modules/searchBar';

export class Main {
    constructor() {
        let searchBar = new SearchBar();
        searchBar.init();
    }
}

let main = new Main();
```

If you want to access the init() function statically:

```
export class SearchBar {
    static init() {
        console.log('work you C*&*T')
    }
}
```

Then accessing it from another file:

```
import { SearchBar } from './modules/searchBar';

export class Main {
    constructor() {
        SearchBar.init();
    }
}

let main = new Main();
```